# Weird thread NullReferenceException when reading value that exists?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an incredibly weird NullReferenceException being thrown when reading a value from a public Field on an object which I know exists. The basic flow is this:

**Edit:** I realized I forgot to mention something important, this does not happen every time I try to read the `Tag` value, but only *somtimes*, enough that I can reproduce it every time by just running the code, but not instantly when the code runs

- Server receives a message  **(Worker thread)**
- The connection that sent the message get gets set as the `Tag` field on the message object  **(Worker thread)**
- The message gets put in a "ReceivedMessages" queue (a normal Queue object which is guarded by locks for serialized access) **(Worker thread)**
- The message gets read **(Main Thread)**
- I try to read the `Tag` field of the message to get the connection, this sometimes returns null and throws an exception, but when the exception gets thrown and I inspect the `Message` object I can see the `Connection` object (which is the object that is in the `Tag` field) there clear as day **(Main Thread)**

If you look at this picture, you will see it clear as day:

[image: Weird thread behavior]

You can see where I marked with the green box, I try to read the `message.Tag` property in three different ways, they all return null as you can see in the part marked with a blue box.

However, if you look at the two areas marked as red, you can see clear as day that the object actually exists. And, just to clear out any confusion, the part where the message gets put on the received messages queue look like this:

*I as you can see I even tried doing a Thread.VolatileWrite to make sure the value gets written*

```
message.Tag = buffer.Tag;

Thread.VolatileWrite(ref message.Tag, buffer.Tag);

if (message.Tag == null)
{
    isNullLog.Add(message.Id);
}

// Queue into received messages
lock (peer.ReceivedMessages)
{
    peer.ReceivedMessages.Enqueue(message);
}
```

The snippet above is all happening in the worker thread, and as you can see I copy the `buffer.Tag` over to `message.Tag`, I even setup a little runtime check for debugging which checks the `message.Tag` for a null value and add it's id to a list called "isNullLog" if so is the case. When the NullReferenceException gets thrown in the main thread, this list is empty.

You also see that i lock the `peer.ReceivedMessages` queue and push the message to the queue *after* i have set the `message.Tag` field.

Also, to be even more clear here is the function that is used to read a message out from the `peer.ReceivedMessages` queue:

```
public bool TryGetMessage(out TIncomingMessage message)
{
    lock (ReceivedMessages)
    {
        if (ReceivedMessages.Count > 0)
        {
            message = ReceivedMessages.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
    }

    ReceivedMessageEvent.Reset();

    message = null;
    return false;
}
```

You can see that I lock the queue even before I check the count, and if it not is empty I set the out property and return true, otherwise I return false.

Honestly I am completely stumped, written several multi-threaded applications before and have never encountered this.

A bit of an update, I have also tried marking the `Tag` field as `volatile`, making it look like this `public volatile object Tag;` but this seems not to be helping.

Comment: I am not a scholar, But I think You are mixing locks with volatile reads and writes.. I think this is the problem. If you use volatile you better use it all the way.. If you are using locks then locks only..

Comment: Hm, not sure if I agree - I have locks where all the threads meet, the volatile part doesn't seem to effect it at all (as in nothing happens if I remove it or add it).

Comment: Is there another thread which operates on the `message.Tag` field (e.g setting it to null)?

Comment: You are right thr, I just noticed the first line: message.Tag = buffer.Tag;

Comment: Hans there is, but it only operates on it when the message gets pushed back into the "used messages" queue, which doesn't happen until I call "TryRecycleMessage(out TIncomingMessage message)". And if the other thread was nulling it, why would it show up WITH a value in the inspector when the exception gets thrown?

Comment: Thanks all for your help, and Hans I wish I could give you "correct answer" because what you said set me on the right track to find the problem (if you read my answer to this question).

Answer (score 2):

I did actually fix this right now, as always when dealing with threads you need to take great care when reading/writing values. I was forgetting to clear the local `message` variable in the receive loop and ended up "reusing" the same message in the next loop iteration, as it has a `if(message == null) { /* create new message */ }` check before each iteration and when I was not clearing this the reading thread ended up trampling all over the "old" message which was stored here when trying to write a new message to it!

Comment: You can have too many checks :)  Don't bother checking or clearing message* object instance variables - just get into the habit of creating a new instance at the start and as as the very next step after queueing one off.